Is there any platform or website can approve nft and token?
this is my first post
Is there any platform auto approve NFT and token erc20.
I have a lot of token but I need to confirm them.
Is there any AI or web site connecting my web3 wallet and approve them?

Sorry. Approve for what? What are you trying to accomplish?

You can approve the tokens directly in the blockchain explorer where the contract is deployed and verified. Simply call the approve function to approve the token you want
